# Tetrahedron height vertices

Tags: 3d, geometry

If given the irregular tetrahedron's vertices coordinates A(x1,y1,z1) B(x2,y2,z2) C(x3,y3,z3) D(x4,y4,z4) and I need to compute the 3d coordinate h(x,y,z) of a height from vertex A. After many google search I was only able to find the barycentric coordinate not the vertex of the height. Please help.

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `(x1, y1, z1 + h)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three points B, C, D define plane `a*x+b*y+c*z-d=0`, where

```
a = y2 * (z3 - z4) + y3 * (z4 - z2) + y4 * (z2 - z3)
b = z2 * (x3 - x4) + z3 * (x4 - x2) + z4 * (x2 - x3) 
c = x2 * (y3 - y4) + x3 * (y4 - y2) + x4 * (y2 - y3) 
d = x2 * (y3 * z4 - y4 * z3) + x3 * (y4 * z2 - y2 * z4) + x4 * (y2 * z3 - y3 * z2)
```

[(derived from mathworld formula (18))](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html)
Normal vector to this plane is (a,b,c).

H point - height from vertex A, so AH vector is normal to BCD plane, and H lies in the plane BCD. H = (x1+k*a, y1+k*b, z1+k*c), and you just have to substitute these coordinates in the plane equation, solve for k coefficient, then calc H point coordinates

substitution: `a*(x1+k*a) + b*(y1+k*b)+c*(z1+k*c)-d=0`

Comment: Thanks! Sorry...probably a very trivial question but how exactly do I calculate k from the plane equation programmatically?